# HTTPS on Google App Engine - redirect in YAML file does not work

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, https, yaml

I have a Python 3 app running on Google App Engine (flexible) without a custom domain. When the app routes from route '/' to '/form' it changes the protocol from https to http. Below is my app,yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -t 300 -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
  
liveness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 300
  timeout_sec: 200
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
  
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
```

I would like to serve all pages/ route using https. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently Redirect http to https on Google App Engine Flexible with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029939/permanently-redirect-http-to-https-on-google-app-engine-flexible-with-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine Flex environment does not support the handlers element in the `app.yaml` and although it's not giving you any error, it's just being ignored. As you can see in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#general), in the yaml reference there's no mention for the handlers block for Flexible. Opposed to that, in the [Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) environment the handlers environment can be specified and it won't be ignored.

Therefore, in order to serve all of the requests from HTTPS instead of HTTP, you will have to force that behavior from the code itself. To do so, you need to include the `Strict-Transport-Security` header in your response. The docs also cover this topic, you can check it out [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections).

Comment: The first step is to simply redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.  Adding the `Strict-Transport-Security` header could break his website if he ever needs HTTP for any reason so be sure you know what you are doing before you do that.

Comment: Thank you, your answers helped me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to my code solved the issue for me:

```
DEFAULT_REFERRER_POLICY = 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'
```